# What is the best method to use when assigning a numerical value from a mySQL database to a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to grab a number value from a mySQL database using PHP.  I'd like to use that number value for some calculations after I've assigned it's value to a variable.  The number value is stored as a float in my database.  My code attempts to connect to my database (which it does successfully), then pull a number value based on parameters passed on by my query, then apply that number value to a variable that I can use in my code.  In my code below, I'm simply trying to print that value to make sure it's pulling properly.  The result I get is this notice: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/max/Desktop/Sites/webprojects/prg/nba/percentchange.php on line 14 Array

Here's my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'NBA');

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo '<p>Error: could not connect to database.</p>';
                exit;
            }

            $rank = "SELECT average FROM nbaCompRankings WHERE team = 'Celtics'";
            $result = $mysqli->query($rank);
            $currentRank = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

echo $currentRank;

The potential solutions I've found on this site use deprecated libraries, so I've been unsuccessful in a search for a solution.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: `$currentRank` will be an associative array. (given that you've used `fetch_assoc()`)

Comment: echo $currentRank[‘average’] to answer your immediate question. But you’re also on the heels of another question: what is the best way to do arithmetic on the number. Floating point can do weird things...

Comment: thanks, Tim!  the math seems to be working out okay for now...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($rank);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $currentRank = $row["average"];
}
```

You should really be preparing your statements though.

```
$team = 'Celtics';
$sql= "SELECT average FROM nbaCompRankings WHERE team = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $team);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($average);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $currentRank = $average;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: sorry, what do you mean when you say 'preparing your statements'?

Comment: You could google it, and find out, but I agree Mason doesn't explain much. Let us use the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: If ‘Celtics’ were to be replaced by a variable, it would be susceptible to injection. Instead, you should use prepared statements which would use a placeholder ( ? or :team) instead of the variable.